# How To Solve Php File Upload Returns Unknown Error

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to uplaoad a file inside my admin page. Firstly my code is shown below:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path_of_dest)) {
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $insert = $db->query("INSERT into files (file_name,file_date,file_size) VALUES ('".$name."',NOW(),'".$size."')");

}else{
    switch($_FILES['image_large']['error']){
        case 1:
            echo "file to large";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "file larger than set in form (MAX_FILE_SIZE)";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "partial upload";
            break;
        case 4:
        default:
            echo "file not uploaded (unknown)";
    }    }
```

It returns an error which is shown below:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/4FAB5EF5-A11A-4A8A-A9F0-31E46E7E9938.JPG): failed to                       open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/dogukangundogan/Desktop      /cem_abi_insan_kaynaklari/admin_panel/backend_op.php on line 40

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/folders/tm/1yfqg4_x6qn4svptkvk7105h0000gn/T/phpZVLimH' to 'uploads/4FAB5EF5-A11A-4A8A-A9F0-31E46E7E9938.JPG' in /Users/dogukangundogan/Desktop/cem_abi_insan_kaynaklari/admin_panel/backend_op.php on line 40
file not uploaded (unknown)
```

Could you help me? I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is the destination path `$path_of_dest` exists?

Comment: All we know is the error is not 1 through 4. What happens if you `var_dump($_FILES['image_large']['error'])` ?

Comment: when I added var_dump($_FILES['image_large']['error'])   to my code, it prints NULL